# Django: How to run a celery task only on start up?

Tags: django, django-models, celery

I have a django app that uses celery to run tasks.

Sometimes, I have a "hard shutdown" and a bunch of models aren't cleaned up.
I created a task called `clean_up` that I want to run on start up.

Here is the `tasks.py`

```
from my_app.core import utils
from celery import shared_task


@shared_task
def clean_up():
    f_name = clean_up.__name__


    utils.clean_up()
```

Here is what `celery.py` looks like:

```
import os

from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab
from datetime import timedelta


os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_app.settings")

app = Celery("proj")


app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")

# Load task modules from all registered Django apps.
app.autodiscover_tasks()

app.conf.beat_schedule = {

    "runs-on-startup": {
        "task": "my_app.core.tasks.clean_up",
        "schedule": timedelta(days=1000),
    },
}


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print(f"Request: {self.request!r}")
```

How can I change `celery.py` to run `clean_up` only on start up?

Extra info:

- this is in a docker compose, so by "hard shutdown" I mean `docker compose down`
- By "on start up" I mean `docker compose up`

Comment: If you only want something to run on startup, don't complicate matters with celery, just execute whatever it is and it'll run on startup.

Comment: HI Mark, Can you elaborate? Where would I put the code?

Comment: It might be best to run your function in the containing apps ready function: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready

Answer (score 1):

you were looking for signal:

`tasks.py` add following code:

```
from celery import signals

@signals.worker_ready.connect
def clean(**kwargs):
    ...
    loggert.info('worker_ready')
```